# Python Type Error (probably simple)

Tags: python

I'm trying open a txt file and read it, but I'm getting a type error and I'm unsure why.  If you you could please provide a reasoning along with the correct syntax, I'm trying to get a better grasp of what's going on underneath.  Here's the code, it's pretty simple I think:

```
from sys import argv

script = argv
filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r" %filename
print txt.read()
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`argv`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a list, not a string. You want

```
script = argv[0]
filename = argv[1]
```

Consider using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) instead of handing `sys.argv` directly:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Print a file.")
>>> parser.add_argument("path", type=str, nargs=1, help="Path to the file to be printed.")
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='path', nargs=1, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help='Path to the file to be printed.', metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>> print args
Namespace(path=[<...>])
```

It looks much more complicated, but it will make your command-line utility much more flexible, easier to expand, and it will ensure you get proper documentation on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, argv is a list of arguments. Open doesn't take a list. That's why you're getting a type error.

Second, open (should) take 2 parameters, the filename and the mode (yes mode is optional, but get in the habit of putting it there. Replace with

```
import sys

script = sys.argv[0]
filename = sys.argv[1]

txt = open(filename, 'r')

print "Here's your file %r" %filename
print txt.read()
```

Comment: Why get in the habit of putting a mode? The point of a default argument is that it's not always necessary.

Comment: Because I had to look up if mode was optional, and what the default value is. That means anyone reading this code might have  to do the same. Which is bad.

Comment: Also add a binary or text mode flag. It makes a difference on Windows. And in Python it *always* makes a difference, so put it in.

Comment: Actually that's not true. It ONLY makes a difference on windows, and python just passes it on to the kernel.

Comment: Sorry, that should say "In Python 3 is *always* makes a difference." I must have slipped in the "3".

Answer (score 0):

argv will be a list, while filename should be a string.

You should probably be using `filename = argv[1]`